# How to create a secure channel in Java?

Tags: tls, java

I am creating a certification server which takes some required details like name, email etc from clients and issues public and private keys using RSA along with digital certificate.

Initially all clients have no keys to enable secure transmission so I need to pass the keys through a secure channel.

What techniques could I use to create secure channel?

I'll be using Java, so please explain any requirements in this language.

Comment: prasad - this site's scope doesn't really include questions of this nature. As zyked pointed out, it looks like you need to conduct some base work to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A secure channel cannot be established unless either (i) the two parties are either using public key cryptography or (ii) the two parties are using a pre-shared secret.

RSA private keys (or any other private keys for that matter) are never meant to be sent. From your question it seems you are not aware of how public key cryptography properly works and I'd suggest you spend a few hours reading first.

If your two communicating parties both have their own private and public key pair, encrypt whatever needs to be sent by the public key of the receiving party. Only the receiving party will then be able to decrypt it by using his own private key. There are various examples of this.